# Помогите определить структуру данных USB-HID устройства

Tags: криптография, usb

Есть устройство: тонометр Beurer BC58 с USB-HID интерфейсом. Мне нужно снимать с него данные, которые он отправляет в родную программу. С помощью сканера порта получил следующие данные:

```
00000302    23.12.2015 16:58:45.959 +0.015  UP  0x00000000  URB_FUNCTION_BULK_OR_INTERRUPT_TRANSFER
000302: Bulk or Interrupt Transfer (UP), 23.12.2015 16:58:45.959 +0.015. (1. Device: USB-устройство ввода) Status: 0x00000000
Pipe Handle: 0x8641f0b4 (Endpoint Address: 0x81)
Get 0x8 bytes from the device
 65 72 20 4B 44 F4 F4 F4                           er KDффф


 000306: Bulk or Interrupt Transfer (UP), 23.12.2015 16:58:46.081 +0.024. (1. Device: USB-устройство ввода) Status: 0x00000000
Pipe Handle: 0x8641f0b4 (Endpoint Address: 0x81)
Get 0x8 bytes from the device
 01 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4                           .ффффффф


 000310: Bulk or Interrupt Transfer (UP), 23.12.2015 16:58:46.185 +0.021. (1. Device: USB-устройство ввода) Status: 0x00000000
Pipe Handle: 0x8641f0b4 (Endpoint Address: 0x81)
Get 0x8 bytes from the device
 73 44 51 0C 17 10 3B 0F
```

Здесь "зашифрована" запись "12/23/2015 04:59 PM 150 93 81", но я не могу определить где она здесь "зашита"

Comment: Есть подозрение, что ковырять саму программу будет проще, чем протокол только по снятым данным.

Comment: "Есть устройство", "получил данные", "здесь зашифрована запись". А чего хотите-то? Вопрос-то где?

Comment: @kff , Поправил вопрос.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , к сожалению, совсем нет опыта реверс-инжиниринга. Подскажите, в какую сторону проще всего копать

Comment: Изучайте IDA Pro.